# zenity doesn't display all list with variables

Tags: zenity

I am making a search and install PPA script for Ubuntu. This script with zenity works 80%, the problem is when this script searches; displays only the first line. I need all lines

```
#!/bin/sh

# simple search and install PPA
# by David Vásquez


if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then
    echo "$*"
else
    echo "No input"
exit
fi

code=$*

cat /dev/null > /tmp/ppa
cat /dev/null > /tmp/ppa-url-tmp


mojito=$(curl https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=$code | grep -e '+archive/' | grep "$code" | awk -F'<td><a href="/~' '{print $2}' | awk -F'">' '{print $1}' | uniq | tr -d '~')

echo $mojito | tr ' ' '\n' | tee -a /tmp/ppa-url-tmp




file="/tmp/ppa-url-tmp"
while IFS= read -r line; do
        # display $line or do somthing with $line
title=$(curl https://launchpad.net/~$line | grep -e '<title>'  | awk -F '<title>' '{print $2}' | awk -F '</title>' '{print $1}' | sed 's/^/"/' | sed 's/$/"/')


description=$(curl https://launchpad.net/~$line | grep -e 'content='  | awk -F 'content="' '{print $2}' | awk -F '.' '{print $1}' | tr -d '/>' | tr -d '"' | sed -e :a -e N -e 's/\n/ /' -e ta | sed 's/^/"/' | sed 's/$/"/') 


support=$(curl https://launchpad.net/~$line | grep -e '<option value='  | grep [0-9] | awk -F '(' '{print $2}' | awk -F ')' '{print $1}' | sed -e :a -e N -e 's/\n/ /' -e ta | awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' | sed 's/^/"/' | sed 's/$/"/' )


echo $title $description $support $line | uniq -u | tee -a /tmp/ppa

zenity --list --radiolist --title="Package installation." --text="Select package to be installed" --width=800 --height=500 --column=In --column=Name --column=Description --column=Compatible --column=PPA "in" "$title" "$description" "$support" "$line"

if [[ "$?" != 0 ]]; then
exit
else

CHECK_INST=$(echo $CHECK | awk -F'|' '{print $5}')

sudo apt-add-repository $CHECK_INST
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get install $code
fi

done <"$file"
```

My other attempt [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76388877/ppa-installerf-zenity3) (same results)

**From terminal a example**

```
myscript pipelight
```

[image]

Comment: @slm if you test: myscript pipeligth
http://s28.postimg.org/47gop2p25/ppaserch.png

Comment: For all also You can see all lines in /tmp/ppa ;)

Comment: @slm I had the same result if I change zenity out the while loop :/

Comment: @slm I need the entire list. In my 3 test https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76388877/ppa-installerf-zenity3 I had the same result :/

Comment: @slm exactly! How did you do? What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description and code it sounds like you're looking for something like this:

[image: ss #1]

To get a dialog that's constructed like this your original script needed to be augmented in a few key ways. For starters you need to move the call to construct the `zenity` dialog so that it's outside your `while` loop that's collecting all the data about the various PPAs.

The other thing lacking was a data structure to store all the bits about the PPAs that you were collecting. For this a Bash array makes the perfect "container" for this data.

```
lines=("${lines[@]}" "FALSE" "$title" "$description" "$support" "$line")
```

This will continue to append the results that you collect via the while loop to an array called `lines`. This array is then given to `zenity`, it contains the column data.

#### Complete script

Here's the whole thing put together, which produced the above screenshot of the dialog.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="ppa-url-tmp"

lines=()
while IFS= read -r line; do
        # display $line or do somthing with $line
title=$(curl https://launchpad.net/~$line | grep -e '<title>'  | awk -F '<title>' '{print $2}' | \
    awk -F '</title>' '{print $1}' | sed 's/^/"/' | sed 's/$/"/')


description=$(curl https://launchpad.net/~$line | grep -e 'content='  | awk -F 'content="' '{print $2}' | \
    awk -F '.' '{print $1}' | tr -d '/>' | tr -d '"' | sed -e :a -e N -e 's/\n/ /' -e ta | sed 's/^/"/' | sed 's/$/"/') 


support=$(curl https://launchpad.net/~$line | grep -e '<option value='  | grep [0-9] | awk -F '(' '{print $2}' | \
    awk -F ')' '{print $1}' | sed -e :a -e N -e 's/\n/ /' -e ta | awk '{print $1, $2, $3}' | sed 's/^/"/' | sed 's/$/"/' )

echo $title $description $support $line | uniq -u | tee -a /tmp/ppa
lines=("${lines[@]}" "FALSE" "$title" "$description" "$support" "$line")

done <"$file"

zenity --list --radiolist --title="Package installation." --text="Select package to be installed" \
    --width=800 --height=500 --column=In --column=Name --column=Description --column=Compatible --column=PPA "${lines[@]}"

if [[ "$?" != 0 ]]; then
  exit
else

  CHECK_INST=$(echo $CHECK | awk -F'|' '{print $5}')

  sudo apt-add-repository $CHECK_INST
  sudo apt-get -y update
  sudo apt-get install $code
fi
```

#### Additional debugging tip

When you're unclear what something is doing in a Bash script reach for the commands `set -x` and `set +x`. These will enable and disable Bash's verbosity which can really help shed light on what's going on. Here's my `zenity` command with just verbosity turned up for it:

```
set -x
zenity --list --radiolist --title="Package installation." --text="Select package to be installed" \
    --width=800 --height=500 --column=In --column=Name --column=Description --column=Compatible --column=PPA "${lines[@]}"
set +x
```

And here's what it looks like when I run `./myscript ...`:

```
+ zenity --list --radiolist '--title=Package installation.' '--text=Select package to be installed' --width=800 --height=500 --column=In --column=Name --column=Description --column=Compatible --column=PPA FALSE '"pipelight-daily : Michael Müller"' '"This PPA provides daily builds of the Pipelight project pipelight-daily "' '"14.04 13.10 13.04"' mqchael/+archive/pipelight-daily FALSE '"Pipelight : Michael Müller"' '"Pipelight allows one to run Silverlight inside a Linux browser using Wine Pipelight "' '"14.04 13.10 13.04"' mqchael/+archive/pipelight FALSE '"pipelight-experimental : “Pipelight Dev Team” team"' '"Experimental packages for Pipelight  pipelight-experimental "' '"14.04 13.10 13.04"' pipelight/+archive/experimental FALSE '"pipelight-daily : “Pipelight Dev Team” team"' '"pipelight-daily "' '"14.10 14.04 13.10"' pipelight/+archive/daily FALSE '"pipelight-stable : “Pipelight Dev Team” team"' '"pipelight-stable "' '"14.10 14.04 13.10"' pipelight/+archive/stable FALSE '"libva : “Pipelight Dev Team” team"' '"libva "' '"13.10 12.10 12.04"' pipelight/+archive/libva
+ set +x
```

The above reveals how all the column components are expanded, properly quoted, by the use of `"${lines[@]}"`.

Comment: Thanks my friend! it worked, thanks for explain. This script going to help to much people.

Comment: @davidva - glad to have been of help and thanks for the interesting Q. Good luck!

Comment: I attempted in Xubuntu doesn't read 'lines=("${lines[@]}" "FALSE" "$title" "$description" "$support" "$line")" . This is the output: 'Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "done").' I do not understand. 
But in Fedora, Arch Linux works :/

Comment: Solved! only change the first line #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/bash